# How to pop a UIViewController on NavigationController and push UIView at the same time

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am facing a problem on `UINavigationController`...

I have this hierarchy

```
UINavigationController
 |- root controller
 |- ViewController A
```

and I have a button in `ViewController A` doing something and push `ViewController B`, but I want to remove `ViewController A` before adding `ViewController B`

So the hierarchy is going like this after the process

```
UINavigationController
 |- root controller
 |- ViewController B
```

It supposed to be sliding from `ViewController A` to `ViewController B`, but if you press back, it return to `root Controller`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the setViewControllers method of the UINavigationController and simply add as an array the root and viewController B

```
//get the existing navigationController view stack
NSMutableArray* newViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];

//drop the last viewController and replace it with the new one!
ViewControllerB *childController = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
[newViewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:newViewControllers.count-1 withObject:self];

//set the new view Controllers in the navigationController Stack
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:newViewControllers animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this might help you.

[iphone NavigationController clear views stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923732/iphone-navigationcontroller-clear-views-stack)

It is rather a different approach to the problem. If you have the instance of required view controller available, you can always pop to it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `[UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:]`

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[rootViewController, viewControllerB] animated:YES];
```

This should result in a push animation.

But to be honest: If you have such a UI, you most like don't want to use a NavigationController in the first place as this confuses the user. The metaphor a UINavigationController implements, is pretty straight forward. You really don't want to mess with that. You might want to have a look into the Apple Human Interface Guidelines and then choose another option of presenting your views!

Comment: Yeah I know it is kind a weird way... but the project requirement need to be done this way... Although your answer is right, Lefteris give more detailed answer :) Thanks

Answer (score -2):

The best method would be to start the navigationController with a new ViewController instead of removing and pushing simultaneously..

on push from ViewController A,

```
[self.navigationController initWithRootViewController:ViewControllerB];
```

Comment: I think navigationController keeps a reference of viewcontroller and hence when you pop it out, it releases it. In your case, whatever you have in navigation controller's stack will become orphan. Have you considered this issue ?  Please let me know if I am wrong about it.

Comment: You NEVER should call ANY init method on an already initialized object! Also you should ALWAYS assign the return value of init as it is allowed to return another object!